# CIVIEvent - List of participants

Tags: civievent, drupal

Bonjour,

i want to add a custom participant listing option (there is a topic 3 years ago but i don't understand the comment).

I create a specific option in Administer CiviCRM / Lists of choice / List of participants.

But how and where i can specified the field i want : Name + default role for example.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Pierre94, Welcome to CiviCRM stack exchange. To add custom listing is not straight forward if you not a developer.

To add custom listing you will need to

**1. Add listing option**

Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Option Groups. Find for 'Participant Listing' and click edit option besides it. Add new option with label as listing name and and Description as class name to invoke when viewing this option eg CRM_Event_Page_ParticipantListing_NameStatusAndDate.

2. Implement the listing using code in your extension

Copy paste any php file from [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/master/CRM/Event/Page/ParticipantListing) into your extension directory(use the path same as defined in your listing option). Similarly do for tpl from [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/master/templates/CRM/Event/Page/ParticipantListing). Modify the php and tpl file as per your needs.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you very much. I do it and it's ok

Comment: Pierre - are you able to 'accept' the above answer, or do you not yet have enough reputation?