# custom public participant listing

Tags: wordpress, civievent

we use wordpress and civicrm to allow our members to register for sports events.

I would like to display in an article for all authenticated member, the list of registered people to all of the week events.

My first intention was to custom or create a public participant list that already exist but :

- it is only for one event
- I don't know how to add the Role (ie Animateur or Participant or Invité) and the comment of the participant (both information entered in the custom profile registration)

Need your advise

Regards,
Hervé

Answer (score 2):

I would use content views wordpress plugin along with content views civicrm integration plugin and data processor civi extension to list what you want.

Comment: thanks for your response - I just passed step 1 with creating my query on data processor

Comment: 2nd step with Content views passed,  but they seem that without the Pro license I cannot display proprely the result of the search

Comment: Hi Pradeep : I took a new direction and created a dedicated reporting by following this post:https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31974/civievent-list-of-participants - It works fine - BR Hervé